# How can I display images in cells?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to display images in a cells of same size like little squares, so that when the first row is full of images it goes automatically to the next row. I did it with an `verticalLayout`, it works very well, but I don t like the final result. Because when the number of images is very big it gives me some vertical lines so I don't see the images clearly:

[image: example]

Here is my code :

```
QStringList fileName =
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this,
                                  tr("Open Image"),
                                  "C:/qt-win-opensource-src-4.5.0/bin/",
                                  tr("Image Files(*.png *.jpg *.bmp *.avi *.gif)"));
QList<QPixmap> PixList;
for (int i=1;i<=fileName.size()-1;i++)
{
    PixList.append(QPixmap(fileName.at(i)));
}

foreach(QPixmap pix, PixList){
    // put the pixmaps one next to the other
    PixLabel = new QLabel(this);
    PixLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    PixLabel->setPixmap(pix);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(PixLabel);
    //ui->gridLayoutWidget->setVisible(true);
}
PixLabel->repaint();
```

Comment: I don't see vertical lines. Could you clarify what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe you can use gridlayout

Comment: what i ment by vertical lines , is that the image is not square

Comment: i did try a gridlayout, the same result